# What is a last version of Visual Svn Server with svn 1.8 can be instaled on Windows XP SP 2?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

What is a last version of Visual Svn Server with svn lib 1.8, can be instaled on Windows XP SP **2**?

I have Windows XP SP **2** machine virtual image and Visual SVN Server with svn 1.7 lib, and I need to upgrade the Visual SVN Server up to svn 1.8 support, but I do not want to upgrade the W-XP to SP3 (becouse we developig and testing our software both on SP2 and SP3 images).

Comment: whats so bad about SP3??

Comment: It's a virtual image for testing tasks

Comment: So you cannot upgrade to SP3?, if you can why do you not want to?

Comment: I have a vmware farm for testing, with Win XP SP2, SP2, W7 etc images. We need to test our svn client both on SP2 and SP3

Comment: Please don't call VisualSVN Server "VSS". VSS is MS Visual SourceSafe! :)

Comment: Corrected in question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You can't.** VisualSVN Server 2.6.0 is the first version with svn 1.8, and the minimum operating system requirement for it is XP SP3.

[image: minimum OS requirement]

Comment: Yes, I read the https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/ carefully and found it now. Thank you.